# display_errors for php5-fpm not working with nginx

Tags: nginx, php

I am running nginx with php5-fpm and want to enable the `display_errors`.
I am running a virtual host, so please help in making a way to enable `display_errors` , `display_startup_errors`.

I tried modifying `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`.

```
;display_errors
Default Value: On
Development Value: On
;Production Value: Off 
;display_startup_errors
Default Value: On
Development Value: On
;Production Value: Off
;error_reporting
Default Value: E_ALL
Development Value: E_ALL
;Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
;html_errors
Default Value: On
Development Value: On
;Production value: Off
;log_errors
Default Value: On
Development Value: On
;Production Value: On
```

Is it require to have multiple `ini` files for each different virtual host, does vhost makes any difference for php configuration ?

I am also trying `set_ini()` , but it is not showing any effect. And I restarted nginx and php5-fpm after making changes in `php.ini` file.

Comment: check your phpinfo() output for your php.ini - keep in mind php ini values can be overridden at "additional ini (dir) files", at php-fpm.conf file, at .user.ini files and of course inside executed php script files

Answer (score 49):

The php.ini does nothing for php-fpm.

**If you are using php-fpm:** You must provide the configuration change in the fpm pool config associated with your web application.  Where these are located depends on your system.  The probably locations are:

- `/etc/php-fpm.d/mydomain.conf` (if things have been set up neatly)
- `/etc/php-fpm.conf` (if you are only using one conf for php-fpm)

Your config paths are different from mine, so poke around to see what you have in there.  Don't make changes in `/etc/php-fpm.conf` if a suitable conf exists in `/etc/php-fpm.d/`.

**If you are not using php-fpm:** Update php.ini with the correct configuration.

**Correct your configuration:** In the configuration shown in the question, you have uncommented documentation rather than provided the correct settings.  You had better undo those changes, because PHP won't understand them.

*The correct lines for php-fpm are:*

```
    ; enable display of errors
    php_flag[display_errors] = on
    php_flag[display_startup_errors] = on
```

*The correct lines for normal php are:*

```
    ; enable display of errors
    display_errors = On
    display_startup_errors = On
```

**Advice:** Do not use these options in a production environment.  Best wishes.

Comment: Note, add these in `; FPM Configuration ;` not under `; Global Options ;`

Comment: Why? I add `php_flag[html_errors]=off` under `; FPM Configuration ;`, but I find it not work:`php-fpm -i |grep html_errors
html_errors => On => On`

Comment: For some reason, I had to use php_admin_flag instead of php_flag, hope this helps someone in the same boat as me

Comment: Is this specific to nginx or PHP 5? Or perhaps distro specific? I run apache2 + php-fpm on Rocky Linux (a CentOS derivative), in my case PHP 7, and it loads the settings in php.ini. The only difference is that restarting httpd doesn't force a reload of php.ini, and to that end you need to restart php-fpm. It seems odd to me that it would ignore this file, at least the way my system is set up the php-fpm configuration files are minimal and it still uses php.ini for most settings.

Comment: @cazort I believe php-fpm will load `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini`, or similar according to your distribution. Unfortunately, I am not current on this, so YMMV.

Answer (score 12):

If you have `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` (used in Debian, Ubuntu style config) then changes to this file should take effect, and that configuration may be further overridden per pool by making changes to specific `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf` files.

Answer (score 7):

In my case Zend errors and NGinX - php5 fpm, work like this:

Only I put in `public/index.php`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Without `If(){...}`

But If only to put above code, display error, will give this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in /usr/local/nginx/html/ZendSkeletonApplication/module/Album/src/Album/Controller/AlbumController.php on line 12
```

Another thing! Set up this code:

```
'display_not_found_reason' => true,
'display_exceptions'       => true,
```

in module.config.php like this:

```
'view_manager' => array(
     'template_path_stack' => array(
         'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
         'display_not_found_reason' => true,
         'display_exceptions'       => true,
     ),
 ),
```

I get all errors of an error.log on screen:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Invalid path provided; must be a string, received boolean' in /usr/local/nginx/html/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Resolver/TemplatePathStack.php:201 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/nginx/html/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Resolver/TemplatePathStack.php(149): Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack->addPath(true) #1 /usr/local/nginx/html/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Service/ViewTemplatePathStackFactory.php(38): Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack->addPaths(Array) #2 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewTemplatePathStackFactory->createService(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'viewtemplatepat...', 'ViewTemplatePat...') #3 /usr/local/nginx/html/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php(939): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend in /usr/local/nginx/html/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 946
```

I didn't touch config file as php-fpm in system (Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 3):

An update for PHP-FPM 7 (under Debian)

1. Go to `/etc/php/[VERSION]/fpm/pool.d`
2. Edit the file `www.conf` (or in case if you have set up other pools, edit those).
3. You want `php_flag[display_errors] = on`
4. Restart with `sudo service php[VERSION]-fpm restart`

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 22.04 you just need to add these lines on the top of your PHP file

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
```