# replacement for php htaccess values in nginx

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx, virtualhost

Okay, I used to use apache - I've now moved over to nginx and I love it, but when it comes to my `.htaccess` values, I'm completely and utterly stuck.

I have this htaccess file:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file Resources/Core.php
php_value short_open_tag On
```

I'm not entirely sure how I can replicate this in nginx. I know I can use the global `php.ini` file, but I don't want to have it on all the virtual hosts, only one of them.

Thanks, 
Tom

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually Tom, NGINX does not consider directory overrides.

You can however change the settings in the virtual hosts settings as:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        expires off;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www//httpdocs/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE   "auto_prepend_file=/var/www/your_folder/Resources/Core.php";
    }
```

the settings file will be found at '/etc/nginx/sites-available' in a default installation in a Linux server, change and restart NGINX

Comment: I'm confused to why you're using `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www//httpdocs/$fastcgi_script_name;` as that folder doesn't exist for me. :/

Comment: Dear @TomDoyle, I have mentioned default folders, you are free to edit it according to your needs. What's important to you is: fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE. Enjoy!

Comment: Huh, I did what you told me and now I'm uh, getting a `No input file specified.` message.

Comment: Did you change 'your_folder' to match your actual file system folder path?

Comment: Okay, it's all in and working but for some weird reason, no PHP errors are showing up! D:

Comment: **Edit:** I fixed the error bug - it was a totally irrelevant thing that was wrong.

Comment: Plese refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929314/display-errors-for-php5-fpm-not-working-with-nginx