# PHP5 - show errors

Tags: php, linux, fastcgi, raspbian, lighttpd

**SOLUTION:**
Bunyamin's comment was my solution.

[display_errors for php5-fpm not working with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929314/display-errors-for-php5-fpm-not-working-with-nginx)

The second answer of that question mentioned the /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf files, in my case /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

There I added

```
php_flag[display_errors] = on
```

and now it works.

**QUESTION:**

I have already turned on error reporting in the /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini file and no errors are shown.

If I add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

to my PHP code, all the errors are shown.

Why doesn't it work if I turn on error reporting in the php.ini files and don't add that code snippet? Shouldn't the php.ini file do the same as the code?

Webserver: Lighttpd
OS: Raspbian Jessie

EDIT:
phpinfo() shows that display_errors is set to Off, but in the php.ini file its turned On.

My php.ini file: http://pastebin.com/1qeK310n

Output of phpinfo(): http://www.file-upload.net/download-11264468/phpinfo.htm.html

Comment: You only need to have one of those, I personally always have `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: which OS you are using ? windows or linux ?

Comment: did you restart apache?

Comment: Depending on _how_ you use php inside your http server environment you need to restart the http server after changing the php configuration for the changes to be picked up.

Comment: Try changing another PHP setting and restarting your webserver, then see if that setting takes affect.. Also you could look at using a .htaccess file todo this

Comment: In a comment below you now state that you are using Lighty, you should have said so in the question. Lighty typically uses php inside a fastcgi server. If that is the case for you then you have to restart that fastcgi server.

Comment: I'm running lighttpd as web server on Raspbian Jessie,
I already restarted the server (sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart and sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart)

Comment: OK, if that really does not pick up changed settings in your configuration file then either you did not really change those files or php uses another configuration file (or none). I suggest you use the famous `phpinfo()` test page to check what configuration file is used.

Comment: phpinfo() says that /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini is the right file, I really changed that one

Comment: display_errors: In line 96 it's a comment, but in line 466 it's not a comment/blocked,
error_reporting: In line 106 it's a comment, in line 449 it's not a comment

Comment: @Mayhem I tried changing another php setting and the change isn't shown in phpinfo()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have four suggestions.

First of all, make sure that you are editing the correct php.ini file. You can see which php.ini file is used with the function **phpinfo()**.

Simply create a file, phpinfo.php, with the following content. When you load the page (http://yoursite.com/phpinfo.php), you can see the details about your PHP configuration.

```
<?php
    echo phpinfo();
```

Secondly, make sure you set error_reporting to E_ALL to get full debug information (Suggested only in development).

Thirdly, is there anywhere in your application that you set display_errors to 0. Sometimes, especially in frameworks, this property is set to 0.

Lastly, sometimes Apache is configured in a way that a custom **php.ini** file located in the root directory of your webpage can override your global configuration. Then the change in global **php.ini** file would not affect your application.

Comment: 1. I already checked, I edited the correct file
2. I set error_reporting to E_ALL
3. I don't think so, I'm only using MariaDB, do you think it sets display_errors to 0?
4. I'm using Lighttpd and there is no custom php.ini file

Comment: One more... write a test script,, In a new base folder in side of www... This will rule out your project.

Comment: I wrote a test script

Comment: Andreas, you wrote a test script outside of your project, and the result is the same? **display_errors** is still set to **0**?

Comment: Yes, display_errors is set to Off although in php.ini it's set to On

Comment: Andreas, would you also add the output of phpinfo() to your question?

Comment: You should check the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929314/display-errors-for-php5-fpm-not-working-with-nginx

Comment: Thank you, the 2nd answer was my solution.
In the /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf file I added php_flag[display_errors] = on
and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You have to scroll down to where the display_errors is set to OFF an then turn it on (Don't uncomment and set to on, scroll down)

Comment: There are 2 one you have to uncomment and one you have to scroll down to find which is default if you have already turned that one On then you may are editing the wron ini file create a php page and look at the output of <?php echo phpinfo()K ?>

Comment: Hmm and is phpinfo() saying the display_errors is turned on or off ?

Comment: In the core section it says that display_errors is turned Off. But in the php.ini file phpinfo() mentions, it's turned On

Comment: Would you care to upload you php.ini file?

Comment: After restarting your webserver the value of display_errors is still Off but the phpinfo() displays it is turned Off? (Where is your webserver running?)

Comment: Yes in the php.ini file it's turned on, but in phpinfo() it's turned off, even after restarting the server.

My webserver is running on Raspbian Jessie