# Apache: Changes to php.ini not picked up

Tags: php

I know that this question is asked a thousand times, but none has given me the correct answer.

I'm trying to get mailhog working and therefor I need to change the `sendmail_path`. I haven't installed sendmail by the way. So I changed my php.ini file, but the changes aren't picked up.

When I run `phpinfo()` it tells me that the loaded configuration file is:

```
/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
```

I edited this php.ini file, restarted apache, but no success. I also restarted `php7.1-fpm`, no succes either. Restarting the whole server also does not change a thing.

When running from CLI, it uses a different php.ini file > `/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini`. I updated this .ini file, restarted apache and from CLI it works fine.

So the issue is that I can't get this working for php-fpm. What else can I do?

Comment: restart php-fpm i guess.

Comment: and check for a second decleration in your file which can rewrite your setting

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, as I mentioned, I did.

Comment: @A.Blub, there are a bunch of other .ini files loaded. You mean that they might overwrite it?

Comment: Probably one of the php-fpm pools overrides your changes. Check the `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/*.conf` files to make sure that it does not happen. You might want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13934612/5914775).

Comment: @TomUdding, there is a www.conf file. But the line with sendmail is commented.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, no, just simpel local Ubuntu server for local development.

Comment: @A.Blub, I checked al ini files, but they all only hold a line like `extension=extension.so`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it fixed on in a different way.

I added a my.ini file in the `/etc/php/7.1/fpm/conf.d/` directory. Added my own modifications to the file and restarted apache and fpm.

Now it picks up te changes and all is working. So the file is added to the **Scan this dir for additional .ini files**.